# Intellij TestNG JDK Settings pass URL

Tags: java, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, testng, browser-automation

So I've been using Intellij and TestNG recently and I know how to get my code to open the webpage I'm testing in my code but I wanted to pass it through TestNG whenever I run my test. I have seen this done before but for the life of me I cant remember, and I've spent ages looking for the answer so this is my last hope, apologies if this is a really basic question!

[image]

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want to do? Do you want IJ to open a browser window when you launch the test, or pass some arguments/parameters into the environment?

Comment: Yes I want IJ to open a browser window navigating to my website and pass that in through TestNG. I believe I have to use a file to do that which I point to in VMoptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making a small confusion here. The option to launch a browser window exists for web-apps run/debug configurations only, since it makes sense:

[image: Web-app run configuration]

I know you're using Selenium, but for TestNG/JUnit it doesn't make much sense to open a browser, since they're simply unit-testing frameworks. Furthermore, in order for selenium to be able to work its magic, it needs to open a browser by itself using a special kind of *driver*.

However, if you'd like to pass some parameters to the TestNG framework into your test class, this is doable from the interface you were showing.

Suppose you have a test case such as:

```java
public class TestNGTest {    
    @Test
    @Parameters({"driver", "url"})
    public void shouldReadParametersSentFromIJ(String driver, String url) {
        System.out.println(String.format("This test would run using the [%s] driver and on the [%s] URL.", driver, url));
    }
}
```

With parameters configured as:

[image: IJ parameter configuration]

This is the result you're going to have:

[image: Execution result]

Comment: @OhAye no problem, glad I could help